# Retrieving data from firebase dynamically in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have my database structured like this in firebase:

```
app root:
        user:
             uid1:
                  some data
             uid2:
                  some data
        helper:
             helper1:
                     some data
```

and so on. I want to retrieve the data from this database. Only some specific data and display it in the app. Also I want download all the images(stored in the firebase storage) from the link provided in helper, and display them in app.

I have tried the documentation for retrieving the data but was unable to retrieve a specific list of data.

**EDIT :-**

```
private DatabaseReference myDb;
myDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

 final String userId = getUid();
mDatabase.child("user").child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
        new ValueEventListener() {

            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                User uData = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            }

        });
```

This is what I learnt from documentation and was doing, it was good for a single valued data but I want to retrieve all the data under user category or helper.

1. How do I iterate through all the data?
2. How do I display a downloaded image from a link into an android app?

I hope it helps now.

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working? Where do you want to display them? Can you explain clearer of what you want to do? Do you want to retrieve ALL these strings (`some data`)? Edit your question and fix it up trying to answer my questions in an indirect or direct way.

Comment: yes i want to retrieve all these strings under helper1 and so on. i want to display it on android app as text. i have tried the official doc of google  for firebase. @AbAppletic

Comment: Edit your question with your code and everything I mentioned above, otherwise you won't get any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over a list of Firebase nodes using `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` (should return an iterable irrc).

**Example:**

```
mDatabase.child("users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
   new ValueEventListener() {
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : datasSnapshot.getChildren() {
               User uData = childSnapshot.getvalue(User.class);
           }
       }

       // onCancelled()...
    }
);
```

You display images in Android using ImageViews. I would recommend checking out the Square's [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) Android image library for some useful functionality.

Comment: can u give me an example of getChildren() with the above example. please.

Comment: Edited with example.